# How to read files in C, in this format ./filec <input.in> <output.myout>

Tags: c, file, input, io

im currently doing a project which works with input files.
The code is doing everything that i want, and its fully correct, the problem is the way im reading the file.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
```

in the terminal im using ./filec input.in, and everything gets printed correctly in the terminal, but i have to open the file in this way:
./filec < input.in > < output.myout > and im not sure what does that entail.

Thank you, and sorry for the poor english

Comment: It would help if you explain what you mean by `< input.in > < output.myout >`  This can quite confusion as a shell interprets the < and > as file redirection operations, and it's quite unclear if that's what you mean.

Comment: Please edit your question to show more code, give more details (what operating system, what compiler, what compilation commands, what is the name of your source file, how did you compile it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a typo and you actually mean:

```
 ./filec < input.in > output.myout
```

Basically, this means you are letting the shell do all the work for you, and your code can simply read from stdin and write to stdout.  You might try:

```
fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
```

Comment: @Alexbot11: This won't work if you pass a non-existent file, e.g. `./myprog some-non-existant-file-name.txt`

Comment: Basile is pointing out that the next line of code must check for errors: `if( fp == NULL) {perror(argv[1]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`

Answer (score 1):

Your `argv[1]` would have the input file, and your`argv[2]` would have the `output` file.

A basic beginning layout for you to work on would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //If there are not three arg, terminate the program.
    }
    FILE *fp_read, *fp_write;
    fp_read = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    fp_write = fopen(argv[2],"w");
    //Do whatever you want with it.
    fclose(fp_read);
    fclose(fp_write);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be you misunderstood the --help option, the first notation you describe is, for commandline arguments, the correct one. "" is just a notation that is used, meaning that you can change the name of the parts between <>.

Anyway, if you really need to use that notation to call your program, you could make a new array containing the argv[1] without <>.

pseudo code:

```
char newFilename[20];

//skip first and last character (if needed, changes values to skip first two and last two chars
for(i = 1; i < argv[1].length - 2; i++){
    newFilename[i - 1] = argv[1][i];
}

fp = fopen (newFilename, "r");
```

**Note** that the < and > characters are interpreted as file redirection operations, so you should do (in this case) ./youprogram "< file.in >" "< file.out >"

Answer (score -1):

First, read about [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) and [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html)

You want to read from `stdin`

When calling `fopen` you *always* should check for failure, e.g. (after having tested that `argc>1`, assuming you defined `int main(int argc, char**argv)` as is conventional!)

```
 FILE *fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
 if (!fp) {perror(argv[1]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

so you probably want:

```
 FILE *fp = NULL; // I prefer always initializing variables
 if (argc>1) {
   fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
   if (!fp) {perror(argv[1]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 }
 else fp = stdin;
```

If you invoke your program as `./myprog < someinput.txt > someoutput.txt` then everything you `printf`, `putchar` or send to `stdout` goes into `someoutput.txt`, and `stdin` is the `someinput.txt`. Generally the redirection is done externally (by the shell on POSIX systems)